# Width property in the XAML

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

What are possible values for Width property in the XAML. I know "Auto" or any number. Is there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be:

`-double`
`-qualifiedDouble`
`-Auto`

For detail information go to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can check the defined values right here --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The grid row definition accepts `*`, too (which means take as much as you can).